# Android existing sqlite database not found

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

To run my code(my app) from Android Studio with AVD manager worked well. First I had a problem with the database not found there but then I used Monitor(DDMS) and just put the file in the right spot: /data/data/thePackagename/databases/database.sqlite

**My app works just fine and all Sqlite queries works just fine if the code just finds the database somewhere!**

Now I'm having problems with finding the actual database on a **real phone(SGS4)** where I have installed my app. 
Correct me if I'm wrong but: I guess I have to copy/move my database from some memory card on my SGS4 to this location: **/data/data/thePackagename/databases/database.sqlite** ...right?
Now how do I do that? Maybe I should just put the database in the internal or the external memory card then just copy it but I dont know how. I have followed some stackoverflow posts but I really dont know what I'm doing:)
Can I really get the database from the assets folder when running on a real UE? This copy trick did not even work with the AVD manager UE. I guess I need some professional help:)

I have used some of the code from here:
[How to use an existing database with an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application?lq=1)

I have tried this but it does not work:

```
        /**
         * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
         * By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
         * of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
         */
        public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
                //check if the database exists
                boolean databaseExist = checkDataBase();

                if (databaseExist) {
                // Do Nothing.
                } else {
                Log.d("Haze", "Create DB...");
                SQLiteDb = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_NAME_AND_PATH, null);
                Log.d("Haze", "Just created DB...");
                copyDataBase();
                Log.d("Haze", "Just copied DB...");
                }// end if else dbExist
                } // end createDataBase().

        /**
         * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
         *
         * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
         */
        public boolean checkDataBase() {
                File databaseFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
                return databaseFile.exists();
                }

        /**
         * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
         * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
         * This is done by transferring byte stream.
         */
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
                //Open your local db as the input stream
                InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
                // Path to the just created empty db
                String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
                //Open the empty db as the output stream
                OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                //Close the streams
                myOutput.flush();
                myOutput.close();
                myInput.close();
                }
```

**Please help me with this problem:)**

Comment: 1024 bytes is a bad size for a file copy operation (way too small). Android phones are using flash memory, therefore use blocks of 16KiB or greater (better 64 or 128 KiB).

Comment: Hi and Thanks for your quick reply:)
My db i big about 172mb
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; ...I should change this to what?

Can I also make a check to see if the file is correctly copied?

Comment: For such large files I would use 521KiB = 524288. Therefore use  byte[] buffer = new byte[524288]; Also encypsulate the copy process in try finally blocks, and close every stream in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can copy your database from the assets folder to your applications database folder. But, you need to understand the process. Extending the `SqliteOpenHelper` class would be used. When you call either the `getReadableDatabase` or the `getWritableDatabase` it checks to see if there is a database in your application database folder. If there is not, then it calls `onCreate` from your `databaseHelper` class where you extended the `SqliteOpenHelper` class. In there you would use your call to `copyDatabase`.